# Magentoのエラーの解決方法[One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running.]

Tags: macos

お力をお貸しください。

Magento初心者のものですが、インストールすると、下記のようにエラーが出ます。

[One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running.]

これを解決するためにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか？
osはmac book air です。

下記を試そうとしたのですが、赤線で引いたところをどこに記述して良いかもわからない素人です。

[image: どこに記述して良いかわからない][image: 現在の状態]

何をどこに記述すれば良いのかをお教えいただけますと、大変助かります。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

コマンドからのインデックス更新ですか。
Macの場合はターミナルを立ち上げて、Magentoをインストールしたディレクトリに移動します。そこで該当のコマンドを実行します。

このあたりはLinuxとかUnixのシェル操作の解説サイトを見てもらったほうが良いでしょう。

なお、MacOSで現在のMagentoを動かすのはあまりおすすめできません。MacportsやHomeBrewで動かすと微妙に動きがLinuxと異なるので期待通り動かないのでやめたほうがいいですね。

簡単に試すのであれば、公式が配布している[DevBox](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/docker/docker-over.html)がMacの場合は楽です。
もちろんGithub等で公開されているVagrantとVirtualboxを組み合わせた仮想マシンでも良いでしょう。